# Heap corruption detected: after normal block(#62)

Tags: c++, heap-corruption

I code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void Nhap(int *x, int y)
{
    for(int i=0; i<y; i++)
        {
            printf("x[%d] = ",i);
            scanf("%d",&x[i]);
        }
}

void Chen(int *a, int *b, int n, int m, int k)
{
    int c[100];
    int x=0;
    for(int i=k; i<n; i++)
    {
        c[x]=a[i];
        x++;
    }
    c[x]='\0';
    x=0;
    for(int i=k; i<m+k; i++)
        {
    a[i]=b[x];
    x++;
        }
    x=0;
    for(int i=k+m; i<m+n; i++)
    {
        a[i]=c[x];
        x++;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<m+n; i++)
        printf("%2d",a[i]);
}


void main()
{
    int m, n, k=0;
    printf("Enter element of b: "); scanf("%d",&m);
    int *b=new int(m);
    printf("Enter element of a: "); scanf("%d",&n);
    int *a=new int(m+n);
    printf("\nNhap a: ");
    Nhap(a,n);
    printf("\nNhap b: ");
    Nhap(b,m);

    printf("\nEnter k: "); scanf("%d",&k);

    Chen(a,b,n,m,k);
    delete[] a;
    delete[] b;
    a=nullptr;
    b=nullptr;

    getch();
}
```

I face error: heap corruption detected: after normal block "#62".

I don't know about it. Thank you for your help. Thank you very much in advance.
I am newbie in C, i am try to fix error but imeffectively. 
I remove 
    delete[]a
    delete[]b
is sucessfully. I don't understand.

Comment: @Ari this looks more like `C+`

Comment: @Streppel Is this "C with a tiny bit of extra stuff" as opposed to "C with a little bit of extra stuff" as was intended with C++?

Answer (score 8):

The statement

```
int *b=new int(m);
```

only allocates *one* integer, and initializes it to the value `m`. If you want to allocate `m` number of integers use

```
int *b=new int[m];
```

Comment: Wonderful, exactly. I fix error successfully. Thank you very much. I love you.